# Change colour of Toolbar Icon for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `MasterDetailPage` that that has a dark background for the Bar Background. I want the Hamburger and toolbar icons to be white but I cant find the setting to change the colour. iOS seems to do it automatically but not Android.

I have tried

```
this.BarTextColor = Color.White;
this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex ("00385E");
this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
```

But nothing is working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Change your android theme to `Theme.Material.Light`

Comment: @Johan this affects more than the icons. All I want to do is tint the icons

Comment: Then use `Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`, this will make android use  light icons on a dark action bar.

Comment: @Johan Its worth mentioning that that works only for Android 5+

Comment: @user1 agreed, alternatively, could use something like this `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`